# V3 maps poly line blocking click listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map and a couple of listeners,

One click listener for drawing points of a poly line and one mousemove listener for the poly line to follow (guide) the user to the next point but the trouble is when the `PolyLine` is directly underneath the cursor preventing the map from receiving the `click` listener.

I'm not sure if this is great design/execution or an edge case for Google Maps.

Is there any way that I can get the click regardless of the poly underneath the cursor?

```
// Listen for mouse stuff.
google.maps.event.addListener($scope.googleMapsInstance, 'click', function($event) {
  // Do something different at each stage
  switch (MyService.currentStage) {
    case MyService.stages.IDLE:
      // Abort any previous attempts.
      if (guide instanceof guideDrawing) {
        guide.abort();
        guide = null;
      }

      // Begin drawing poly line.
      guide = new guideDrawing($event.latLng);

      // Update the current stage.
      MyService.currentStage = MyService.stages.APEX_GUIDE_START;
    break;

    case MyService.stages.GUIDE_START:
      // Update the stage
      MyService.currentStage = MyService.stages.GUIDE_END;

      // Send the new coordinates
      guide.finish($event.latLng);
    break;
  }
});

// Update the poly line with the mouse.
google.maps.event.addListener($scope.googleMapsInstance, 'mousemove', function($event) {
  // If we haven't started, just exit;
  if (!guide || MyService.currentStage !== MyService.stages.GUIDE_START) {
    return;
  }

  // Send the new coordinates
  guide.update($event.latLng);

  // Draw the polyline.
  guide.draw($scope.googleMapsInstance);
});
```

Comment: one way would be to set the [polylineOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) 'clickable' to false

Comment: Exactly right, would you mind putting an answer so I can mark it correct otherwise I shall just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to set the [polylineOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) to 'clickable:false